# How do I make a reservation system for purchasing tickets in mysql using php?

Tags: php, mysql

**Two problematic scenarios:**

- What if 2 users want to purchase 1 ticket each and 1 ticket is in stock?
- What if 3 users want to purchase 1 ticket each and 2 tickets are in stock?

I want to be able to ‘reserve’ the tickets whilst they are in the Payment Gateway. This means that the tickets are still not purchased but are currently reserved to the user in question so that no other user can purchase them while the first user is still in the payment process.

**I have two tables in my database:**

**1.** Ticket_type_id: contains a type of ticket

- ticket_type-id
- name
- description
- stock_remaining

**2.** Ticket_purchased: contains all purchased tickets

- ticket_id
- ticket_type_id
- user_id

When a ticket is being purchased the correct amount should be reduced from the 'stock_remaining' and reserved while the person is in the payment gateway. Only after the payment has succeeded should all the tickets be created in the second table and the deduction from the 'stock_remaining' is final.

---

**So far I came up with the following process (My try code):**

When the user clicks on “check out” a **PHP session** is started. The PHP begins a **Transaction within the Data Base**. This transaction deducts from the tickets stock total and generates tickets for the given user but **doesn’t commit**.

If any of the following queries fails the whole **transaction is Rolled Back**, the **Session is closed** and the user is given an error message. However if it succeeds, the **payment gateway is opened**.

Once the gateway is completed, payment is successful and the user returns from the gateway I use **Volley** to send a success parameter to the running **session**. If success the Transaction commits, else it rolls back.

```
session_start(); 
    $response = array();
    begin(); // transaction begins

if (isset($_POST['ticketTypeId']) && isset($_POST[‘ticketQuantity’]) && isset($_POST['userId'])){

$ticketTypeId = $_POST['ticketTypeId'];             
$ticketQuan = $_POST['ticketQuantity'];
        $userId= $_POST['userId'];

    $query1 = check if quantity required is available   
    $query2 = deduct quantity from total remaining
ForLoop(ticket quantity){
$query3 = generate one ticket for user
}

    if(!success){
        // On SUCCESS
        $response["success"] = 1;
            echo json_encode($response);
    }else{
        // On Failed
        $response["success"] = 0;
            echo json_encode($response);

            rollback(); // transaction rolls back
        exit;
}   
}


if (isset($_POST['Transaction'])){

$transaction =  $_POST['Transaction'];
    if($transaction == 1){ 
        // On Success
        $response["success"] = 1;
            echo json_encode($response);
         commit(); // transaction is committed
         exit; 
    }else{
        // On Failed
        $response["success"] = 0;
            echo json_encode($response);
        rollback(); // transaction rolls back
                exit;
    }
}
```

I don't know how to reconnect to the session so I don't know if this works.

Comment: Hi please concider posting your try(code). Nobody want done your work :)

Answer (score 0):

For the problematic situation of selling 1 ticket, while 2 request it you may want to either lock 1 ticket after someone puts it in his cart or/and you may use transactions on MySQL.

The same issue happens on creditcarts. When two carts try to pull the maximum creditlimit the same time. only the first gets served.. hopefully ;)